# Default year in Date if dateString does not have year part

Tags: javascript, date

I was trying to check what values would return if partial values are sent.

```js
var d = new Date("11/28");
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString())
```

I was expecting it to be `28th Nov., 2016(current year)`, but it returns `28th Nov., 2001`.

So the question is **Why is *2001* considered as default year**?

Comment: @BasimHennawi That does not explain why it returns `2001`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I'm asking Why it returns 2001 as default

Comment: It is because of _rules of the user's own computer_

Comment: i get `Invalid Date`.

Comment: @Rayon I didn't know this.

Comment: It seems to be specific to Chrome. Firefox returns an invalid date.

Comment: @Community, This is not duplicate. Please check

Answer (score 5):

2001 is not consider as default year.
This is a Chrome issue, if you run the same code with Firefox you get `Invalid Date`.

Comment: Though this is the correct answer, it will not add much to SO. Can you please remove answer, so I can delete the post?

Answer (score 1):

The [*language specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.parse) only includes rules for parsing ISO 8601 formatted strings. Parsing of any other format is implementation dependent (noting that the Date constructor and Date.parse are equivalent for parsing).

So given "11/28" is not a valid ISO 8601 string, the implementation is free to apply any heuristics it likes. Any result, including an invalid date, should be expected and consistency between implementations should not.