# Chrome defaults to year 2001 when initializing a Date instance with no Year provided

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date

When initializing a new `Date` instance in `Chrome`, if the provided value is a partial date string (with no year set), `Chrome` defaults the Year to 2001. 
This behavior is different than other browsers such as `Firefox`, which returns `"Invalid Date"` in such case.

For example:
`new Date('05/22')` will result to May 22, 2001

Is there any specific reason they use 2001 as the default year and not the current year? 
Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Can you show an example of how you're actually initialising it?

Comment: I had asked the same question long time back. You can check this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504116/default-year-in-date-if-datestring-does-not-have-year-part

Comment: @JamesThorpe You can try `new Date('11/20')`. I have a snippet in my related post. You can even check that.