# Moment.js default year is 2001

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

**Description of the Issue and Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Receive user input as 3/3 `var response`
2. Parse into a date variable `var date = moment(new Date(response))`
3. Doing a console.log of date gives `moment("2001-03-03T00:00:00.000")`

The year defaults to 2001. Since the user may input the date in their own format, I didn't want to add in a format as I wouldn't know what format they might want to enter.

After looking around, I found some Moment github issues on this ([#635](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/635), [#912](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/912)) which mentioned that the issue was resolved, but I am still getting the default year of 2001.

I also found a suggestion to set the year as this year if left unspecified:

```
if (date.year() === 2001) {
    date.year() = moment().year();
}
```

This works, but feels like a dirty solution. Any ideas what I can do instead?

Thanks in advance!

**Current Environment**

1. Node.js `v8.9.4`
2. Moment.js `v2.20.1`
3. VS code `v1.19.3`
4. MS Bot SDK `v3.14.0`

p/s Still pretty new to the stackoverflow/ github issues, and not to sure where I should have posted instead. Please let me know if you need more information!

Comment: Nothing to do with moment. `new Date('3/3')` returns it in 2001.

Comment: Hi, I added that because otherwise, moment would return me a depreciation warning, not unlike the one here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263380/deprecation-warning-moment-construction-falls-back-to-js-date) Removing it also returns `moment("2001-03-03T00:00:00.000")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388495/chrome-defaults-to-year-2001-when-initializing-a-date-instance-with-no-year-prov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `moment` with a format string to ensure the format is proper. You might want to force the user to provide the year or use a date picker. The machine can only do so much

```js
console.log(moment('3/3', 'MM/dd').toString());
// or
console.log(moment('3/3', 'dd/MM').toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```